# What PowerShell/WSMan clients or queries are consuming more than 1000 requests per 2 seconds?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, winrm

Exchange 2010 remote administration tools are complaining with the following error

```
[txexmb02.ibm.com] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot
process the request. The system load quota of 1000 requests per 2 seconds has been exceeded. Send future requests at
 a slower rate or raise the system quota. The next request from this user will not be approved for at least 558475776 
milliseconds. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed
VERBOSE: Connecting to TXEXHC02.ibm.com
```

The [help document this error referrers to](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347642.aspx) says this is a WS-Man error.

We're running SCOM 2007 R2 and am thinking that is increasing the query count, but I need to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get some insight into Powershell/WS-Man sessions by using this command:

```
Get-WSManInstance -ConnectionURI http://myserver.contoso.com:5985/wsman shell -Enumerate
```

This command can be run locally or on the remote server. myserver.contoso.com represents the remote server all of your clients are connecting to. You'll see information on about each open session, their state and memory usage.

Comment: Thanks! I ran the command with the ConnectionURI and without, and it returned zero results.  Perhaps there is another way to identify the offending client / process

Comment: I would try making a remote connect to your server and then running the command to verify you are getting some results